# How to use mongodb-express with MeteorJS' MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, user-interface, meteor

I'm building an application in MeteorJS.

I want to have GUI access to built-in MongoDB database.

So I found: https://github.com/andzdroid/mongo-express
I installed it, configured it to connect to localhost:3001.

Since mongodb doesn't have a default admin password, I tried to create it by:

```
meteor mongo
use admin
db.addUser("admin","password")
```

then I set

```
adminUsername: 'admin',
adminPassword: 'password',
```

in **mongo-express\config.js**.

However when I open **localhost:8081**, it asks me login credentials again and even if I insert them manaully (admin, password) it doesn't work.

So I went back to **meteor mongo**, tried to create admin user again and go error

> Error: couln't add user: User admin@admin" already exists

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify. You are looking for a web-based Shell. Tools like RoboMongo will not do the trick for you?

Comment: I installed Robomongo. thanks for the advice. However the error is the same. connection successful, authentication failed

Comment: Maybe we should continue on a chat, but can you tell us where is the error prompting and try and paste the whole message, too.

Comment: I don't know how to start a chat until SO suggests me to. feel free to start one. I don't really know how to explain better than error, other than "auth failed"

Answer (score 0):

edit /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongo-express/config.default.js

find and edit to:

```
} else {
  mongo = {
    db:       'meteor',
    host:     'localhost',
    password: '',
    port:     3001,
    ssl:      false,
    url:      'mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor',
    username: '',
  };
}
```